# Is there a general method of finding the number of Sylow p-subgroups, given only the order of the group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Given that one is only told the order of the group, one will often reach conclusions as "its either $1$ or $x$ Sylow $p$-subgroups." Is there a general method to find out if one can rule one of the alternatives out, given only the order of the group? (That is, I am aware of the fact that for some orders we have to content with "$1$ or $x$, but I have also seen--seen, not understood--cases where one can rule one of the alternatives out.")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer you question quickly, yes. There are more parts to Sylow's Theorem than more people are usually aware. Two of them are

**Thm:** If $G$ is a finite group, $p$ a prime and $p^n \mid o(G)$ but $p^{n+1} \nmid o(G)$, then any two subgroups of $G$ of order $p^n$ are conjugate.

**Corollary:** The number of $p$-Sylow subgroups in $G$ equal $o(G) / o(N(P))$, where $P$ is any $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$.

Does this help?

Comment: I am not familiar with the notation $o(G)$. An example that handles the problem I've described would also be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is not hard to guess what $o(G)$ means - the same as $|G|$ I expect.

Comment: Sure, we know there are precisely $|G:N(P)|$ $p$-Sylow subgroups for $P$ any Sylow subgroup. I challenge you to find a $2$-Sylow subgroup of $S_{6}$ explicitly, and find it's normalizer, *and* calculate the index. =) For example, if we consider ${\rm GL}(3,\Bbb F_p)$, one can show a $p$-Sylow of that is the set ${\rm UT}(3,\Bbb F_p)$ of upper triangular matrices with ones in the diagonal.

Comment: $o(G) \equiv |G|$, namely the group order. The example suggested by Tamaroff would be excellent to demonstrate. I can try to come up with a neat example.